# Best way to define / declare structured data in Mathematica? (for NAO robot link properties)

Tags: data-structures, wolfram-mathematica, nao-robot

I am simulating a NAO robot that has published physical properties for its [links and joints](http://users.aldebaran-robotics.com/docs/site_en/reddoc/hardware/masses_3.3.html) (such as dimensions, link mass, center of mass, mass moment of inertia about that COM, etc).
The upper torso will be static, and I would like to get the lumped physical properties for the static upper torso. I have the math lined out (inertia tensors with rotation and parallel axis theorem), but I am wondering what the best method is to structure the data.

Currently, I am just defining everything as rules, a method I got from looking at data Import[]'d from struct's in a MAT file. I refer to attributes / properties with strings so that I don't have to worry about symbols being defined. Additionally, it makes it easier to generate the names for the different degrees of freedom.

Here is an example of how I am defining this:
http://pastebin.com/VNBwAVbX

I am also considering using some OOP package for Mathematica, but I am unsure of how to easily define it.

Comment: I just realized that I could find an OOP package and then use something like MathOO and define it all using constructors... I will be trying this out too.

Comment: Although the couple of OOP packages for Mma are interesting, I don't think that they really work performance-wise... I think that just using `DownValues` is easiest - it's what Mma is optimized for.  Daniel Lichtblau and others have given talks about [data structures in Mma](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/321/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this task, I had taken a look at Lichtblau's slides but could not figure out a simple way to apply it towards defining my data structure. I ended up using MathOO which got the job accomplished since efficiency was not too much of a concern and it was more or less of a one-time deal.